# How to access the current element in a selector?

Tags: jquery

I want to avoid the overhead of calling `$("#)` again and wanted to reference the element that is already selected in the selector, something like using `this`

any help?

```
$("#aModel1").click(function () {
  alert( ??? .attr("myattribute")  );
});
```

Comment: Use `$(this).attr("myattribute") `

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `$(this)` will do it

```
$("#aModel1").click(function () {
    alert( $(this).attr("myattribute")  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you cant use

```
this
```

??

```
$("#aModel1").click(function () {
  alert($(this).attr("myattribute")  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event handler `this` is usually binded to the source element:

```
$("#element").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('myattribute'));
});
```

Or you can save the reference to the element:

```
var element = $("#element");
element.click(function() {
  alert(element.attr('myattribute'));
});
```